# HTML Code for text checkbox ''

Tags: html

Is there an HTML code for the text checkbox ''?

EDIT: So to be clear, I need the HTML Number for the symbol , not the form element checkbox.

Comment: What do you mean by text checkbox? Is that supposed to be the UTF character you pasted?

Comment: So are you finding something like `&checkbox;` (of course this one is not exist) so that it would become ``?

Comment: I guess I am looking for the HTML number for that symbol. So for example &#60; equals '<'  - is there such a symbol for the ?

Comment: @Thomas: why use numerical entities? Just paste the symbol into the source code directly.

Comment: @Konrad: Just pasting the symbol won't necessarily work if the HTML file would otherwise be ASCII, Latin-1, or Windows-1252.  As would be the usual case in Windows as well as most *nix environments.

Comment: @cHao: pardon me but using anything other than a Unicode transform encoding (i.e. UTF-x) for HTML is brain-dead. Ten years ago this would have been forgivable. Now, it’s not.

Comment: @Konrad: I might agree if i ever had a need for an HTML file that contained anything but ASCII characters.  HTML has its own way of including Unicode chars; why not use it and remove the need to even *care* what encoding the file is in?

Comment: @cHao: sorry but this is a very US-centric view and it just doesn’t square with the rest of the world. If you really have the liberty of not caring for encodings in your project, good for you. But you’re the exception. For non-English texts HTML’s way of allowing Unicode sucks, compared to a proper encoding. So there’s just no way around it for the rest of us.

Comment: @Konrad: I don't care about the rest of the world.  I care about the current file.  Unless you can guarantee that it's in UTF-(8|16), and not one of the *dozens* of other encodings out there, it's irresponsible to say "just paste the symbol".  Better to use the way that's guaranteed to work regardless of the actual file's encoding.

Comment: @cHao: that’s my point, though. You *should* be able to tell, for each of your files, what encoding it’s in. If you can’t, you’re doing something fundamentally wrong (especially as a programmer). As Joel said: [There Ain’t No Such Thing As Plain Text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). For HTML files in particular you should **always** specify an encoding (either in the file itself or in the HTTP header), **no exception**. (And it should be in an UTF encoding.)

Comment: @Konrad: I'd agree with the first part, but not necessarily the second.  Whatever encoding you use, yeah, you should know -- and you should specify.  But no, it need not be UTF, if you have no need for that.  If you're communicating in English, or even French or German, the ability to encode Sanskrit in your text is just plain overkill.  Either way, though, it's not *your* file, so **you don't know what encoding it's in**, so **you can't say whether it even works.**  Joel's point applies both ways, ya know.

Comment: @cHao: But for HTML files specifically there is *no drawback* of using UTF-8 at all. There is no cost. There is no overkill. There is nowadays no reason whatsoever to use anything else (except perhaps UTF-16 or UTF-32). Certainly there’s no reason to use Windows CP-1252 or ISO-8859-1 (“ANSI” and “ASCII”, respectively – the latter *is interpreted wrong by all browsers* anyway) since it won’t be different from UTF-8.

Comment: @Konrad: But there *is* a drawback.  There *is* a cost.  If you're communicating in French, for example, using one of the ISO-8859 charsets means one byte per char, even for the accents and curlies on the Cs.  In UTF-8, it's at least 2 bytes for each of those, and potentially a lot more if your editor for some reason uses compatibility sequences ('e' + 'acute accent' rather than 'e with acute accent').

Comment: BTW, ISO-8859-1 is *not* ASCII -- it's "Latin-1", which (like most 8-bit charsets) is compatible with ASCII but also has chars for the upper 128 byte values.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This will do:

```
&#x25a2;
```

It is ▢
(known as a "WHITE SQUARE WITH ROUNDED CORNERS" on [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a2/index.htm))

Or

```
&#x25fb;
```

as ◻
(known as a "WHITE MEDIUM SQUARE" on the same website)

Two with shadow:

```
&#x274f;
&#x2751;
```

as ❏ and ❑ . The difference between them is the shadows' shape. You can see it if you zoom in or if you print it out.
(They are known as "LOWER RIGHT DROP-SHADOWED WHITE SQUARE" and "LOWER RIGHT SHADOWED WHITE SQUARE", respectively).

You can also use

```
&#x2610;
```

which is ☐
(known as a "BALLOT BOX").

A sample is at  http://jsfiddle.net/S2QCt/267/

(a note: on the Mac, `&#x25a2;` is quite nice, because it is bigger and somewhat more elegant than `&#x2610;` On Windows, `&#x2610;` looks more standard, while `&#x25a2;` is somewhat small.)

Comment: Note that 25fb doesn't display for me (FF4b6, WinXP) so it may require special fonts to be installed for some users.

Answer (score 140):

U+F0FE `` is not a checkbox, it's a Private Use Area character that might render as anything. Whilst you can certainly *try* to include it in an HTML document, either directly in a UTF-8 document, or as a character reference like `&#xF0FE;`, you shouldn't expect it to render as a checkbox. It certainly doesn't on any of my browsers—although on some the ‘unknown character’ glyph is a square box that at least looks similar!

So where does U+F0FE come from? It is an unfortunate artifact of Word RTF export where the original document used a symbol font: one with no standard mapping to normal unicode characters; specifically, in this case, Wingdings. If you need to accept Word RTF from documents still authored with symbol fonts, then you will need to map those symbol characters to proper Unicode characters. Unfortunately that's tricky as it requires you to know the particular symbol font and have a map for it. See [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905071818/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/murrays/archive/2008/01/24/weird-f020-f0ff-characters-in-word-s-rtf.aspx) for background.

The standardised Unicode characters that best represent a checkbox are:

- `☐`, U+2610 Ballot box
- `☑`, U+2611 Ballot box with check

If you don't have a Unicode-safe editor you can naturally spell them as `&#x2610;` and `&#x2611;`.

(There is also U+2612 using an X, `☒`.)

Answer (score 21):

**Use the Unicode Character**

**&#10004;**   **=   ✔**

---

Answer (score 13):

I have compiled a list of all special square characters that are mentioned here, and more checkbox characters:

| Unicode-Nr. | HTML-Code | Zeichen | Offizieller Name | Beschreibung |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+00058 (88) | `&#x00058;`, `X` | X | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X | Großer Buchstabe X |
| U+237B (9083) | `&#x237B;` | ⍻ | NOT CHECK MARK | Durchgestrichenes Häkchen |
| U+2573 (9587) | `&#x2573;` | ╳ | LIGHT DIAGONAL CROSS | Dünnes diagonales Kreuz |
| U+25A1 (9633) | `&#x25A1;`, `&square;` | □ | WHITE SQUARE | Weißes Quadrat |
| U+25A2 (9634) | `&#x25A2;` | ▢ | WHITE SQUARE WITH ROUNDED CORNERS | abgerundetes Quadrat |
| U+25FB (9723) | `&#x25FB;` | ◻ | WHITE MEDIUM SQUARE | mittleres Kästchen |
| U+2610 (9744) | `&#x2610;` | ☐ | BALLOT BOX (1) | Kästchen (für Wahl, Stimmzettel) |
| U+2611 (9745) | `&#x2611;` | ☑ | BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK (1) | Abgehaktes Kästchen |
| U+2612 (9746) | `&#x2612;` | ☒ | BALLOT BOX WITH X (1) | Angekreuztes Kästchen |
| U+2613 (9747) | `&#x2613;` | ☓ | SALTIRE | Andreaskreuz |
| U+26DD (9949) | `&#x26DD;` | ⛝ | SQUARED SALTIRE (2) | Quadrat-Andreaskreuz |
| U+26F6 (9974) | `&#x26F6;` | ⛶ | SQUARE FOUR CORNERS (2) | abgerundete Quadratecken |
| U+2705 (9989) | `&#x2705;` | ✅ | WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK | Weißes fettes Häkchen |
| U+2713 (10003) | `&#x2713;`, `&check;` | ✓ | CHECK MARK | Häkchen |
| U+2714 (10004) | `&#x2714;` | ✔ | HEAVY CHECK MARK | Fettes Häkchen |
| U+2715 (10005) | `&#x2715;` | ✕ | MULTIPLICATION X | Kreuzchen als Malzeichen für Multiplikation |
| U+2716 (10006) | `&#x2716;` | ✖ | HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X | fettes Kreuzchen als Malzeichen |
| U+2717 (10007) | `&#x2717;`, `&cross;` | ✗ | BALLOT X | Kreuzchen (wörtl. „Wahlkästchen-X“) |
| U+2718 (10008) | `&#x2718;` | ✘ | HEAVY BALLOT X | Fettes Kreuzchen |
| U+274C (10060) | `&#x274C;` | ❌ | CROSS MARK | Kreuzzeichen |
| U+274E (10062) | `&#x274E;` | ❎ | NEGATIVE SQUARED CROSS MARK | Negatives Kreuzzeichen im Quadrat |
| U+274F (10063) | `&#x274F;` | ❏ | LOWER RIGHT DROP-SHADOWED WHITE SQUARE | Weißes Quadrat unten rechts abgetrennt schattiert |
| U+2A2f (10799) | `&#x2A2f;`, `&Cross;` | ⨯ | BALLOT X | Kreuzchen (wörtl. „Wahlkästchen-X“) |
| U+1F5F8 (128504) | `&#x1F5F8;` |  | LIGHT CHECK MARK (1,2) | Dünnes Häkchen |
| U+1F5F9 (128505) | `&#x1F5F9;` |  | BALLOT BOX WITH BOLD CHECK (1,2) | Fett abgehaktes Kästchen |
| U+1F7AC (128940) | `&#x1F7AC;` |  | HEAVY SALTIRE (1,2) | Fettes Andreaskreuz |

All of these glyphs are displayed mostly correctly on my Windows 10 notebook (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) and my smartphones, but:

(1) not under Android 10, Samsung S9

(2) not under iOS 14, iPhone 7

see https://blog.dmr-solutions.com/blog/checkbox-zeichen-in-html (in german)

Answer (score 6):

☑

this is a character . You can do copy/past without problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for the character you posted in your question: `&#xf0fe;`

But that's not a checkbox character...

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your HTML file is encoded with UTF-8 and that your web server sends a HTTP header with that charset, then you just can write that character directly into your HTMl file.

http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

If you can't use UTF-8 for some reason, you can look up the codes in a unicode list such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters and use `&#xABCD;` where ABCD is the hexcode from that list (U+ABCD).

Answer (score 0):

As this has already been properly answered, I'd just add the following site as a reference:

[Unicode Table](https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/table/)

You can search for "check", for example.

Comment: FYI: if you go to that site and search for "check", you won't find an empty checkbox. I guess that site is incomplete. You will find something like what the OP wants under "ballot box".